# mvvmcross ios method binding (RIO)

Tags: ios, binding, mvvmcross

Is there a way to achieve **method binding** in iOS with MVVMCross ?
I cannot see an example of such a binding in the vids or tutorials...

**ImageNavigationViewModel**:

```
    public void NavigateLeft()
    {
        if (!this.HasLeftSisters.Value)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.currentNodeIndex--;
        this.Update();
    }
```

**ImageNavigationView**:

```
private UIButton navigateLeftButton;
...

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ImageNavigationView, ImageNavigationViewModel>();
set.Bind(this.navigateLeftButton).To(vm => vm.NavigateLeft);
```

I have a compile-time error since it's expecting an object (ICommand).

I tried this too:

```
set.Bind(this.navigateLeftButton).To("NavigateLeft");
```

And have runtime error: *Failed to create target binding for binding TouchUpInside for NavigateLeft.*

I ended up adding a **ICommand** to my view model, which is a bit disappointing since I "method bind" just find in Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rio Method binding is available in iOS

It's demonstrated in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-5XQlcVj2Y with sample cod ein https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-36-Rio/BindMe.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs#L58

Your line:

```
  set.Bind(this.navigateLeftButton).To("NavigateLeft");
```

should work - but you will need the method binding plugin added to the Touch UI project to enable this extension.